# grep ".* bk.*\.log"

Tags: unix, ksh

I wonder what is below code grepping ?

```
ls -lrt | grep ".* bk.*\.log"
```

I thought it is listing all files which are starting with bk and ending with log. 
Could someone verify that.

Comment: if I'm reading it correctly, it should `<anything><space>bk<anything>.log`

Answer (score 1):

"listing all files which are starting with bk and ending with log"

Then you can use: `ls -lrt bk*log` -- don't need grep at all.

You might want to read the bash documentation for [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion).

Comment: what if I add underscore (_) instead of star(*) ?

Comment: Then you'd list only the file named "bk_log". Underscore is just matched as a literal underscore -- not a shell glob.